# problem in using bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have the following issue:

```
First activity
```

The android camera is opened and the user can take a picture.Once the picture is taken the second activity is launched.

```
Second activity
```

In this activity the user has the posibility to view the photo.
For that I receive from the first activity the picture, like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

and I create the following bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        options.inDither = true; 
        byte[] imageData = extras.getByteArray("imageData");
        myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                imageData.length, options);

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(90);
        bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.getWidth(),
                myImage.getHeight(), mat, true);
        //...operations on the bitmapResult
```

The result bitmap is the stored into the `sdcard` and before leaving this activity I recycle my bitmap in order to avoid memory issue:

```
bitmapResult.recycle();
bitmapResult=null;
```

After all this is done we move on to activity 3.

```
Third activity
```

In this activity the user can see the picture in different size.The picture is taken from the `sdcard`.

The big problem is when the user hits the back button is taken from the activity `three` to activity `two`, but my app crashes because is trying to do `operations on bitmap that has been recycled.`

And if I don't recycle the bitmap in the second activity I get `OutOfMemeory Exception` when I go a few times up and down through my application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered reloading the bitmap from SD card in onResume method of the second activity?

Comment: the problem is that what I save on the sdcard is the final version, after I've done all the operations on it.If I will reload it,it means I'll do the operations twice on it!

Comment: Then probably the best thing would be to have a copy bitmap of the original image in the second activity which you would recycle only when the activity is destroyed (ie. when you go back from second to first activity) and keep it in memory while third activity is running. This way you would avoid out of memory exceptions and still  have the copy of the image when resuming second activity.

Answer (score 0):

When your user is in ***Activity 2*** *don't* go directly to **Activity 3** (the gallery). 
First, finish **Activity 2** and return a result to **Activity 1**. Then start **Activity 3**.

Your first/main activity:

```
public class TakeAPicture extends Activity {

    public static final int REQUEST_PICTURE_WAS_TAKEN = 100;
    public static final int REQUEST_SHOW_GALLERY = 101;
    public static final int RESULT_PICTURE_WAS_TAKEN_SHOW_GALLERY = 102;
    public static final int RESULT_BACK_FROM_GALLERY = 103;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.takeapicture);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        PictureTaken.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_PICTURE_WAS_TAKEN);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PICTURE_WAS_TAKEN:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_PICTURE_WAS_TAKEN_SHOW_GALLERY) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Gallery.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_SHOW_GALLERY);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your second activity you have to do something like this:

```
public class PictureTaken extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picturetaken);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PictureTaken.this
                        .setResult(TakeAPicture.RESULT_PICTURE_WAS_TAKEN_SHOW_GALLERY);
                PictureTaken.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Regards